# What does this sequence of short words starting with a 'd' mean?

Tags: translation

What does:

> der den des den die die der der des des das den

mean? It's the only thing I remember from German at school.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. I'm sorry that I cannot understand what you are asking. All you listed are the german articles `der, die, das` with more or less correct all 4 grammatical cases in a row (nominativ, genitive, dative, accusative) for each article. So `die die der der` is for "die".

Comment: I cannot understand why you would not think this should be “put on hold” as “off topic”.

Comment: Read this: Bestimmter Artikel: http://www.udoklinger.de/Deutsch/Grammatik/Artikel.htm

Answer (score 7):

You slightly misremembered them, but those are [the declensions of the definite articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_articles#Definite_article) in German. They all mean the same as the word 'the' in English, but they are used in different circumstances depending on the (grammatical) gender of the noun and how the noun is used in a sentence (as subject, (in)direct object, after a preposition).

[image]

By Parcly Taxel - Own work, CC BY-SA 4.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=39661284